# How to make invalidating Beaker cache work?

Tags: python, caching, bottle, beaker

I have a function which is decorated with beaker cache decorator. The function is located in a module from which it is imported into the main app.

```
from caching import cache, my_cached_function
```

Now, in one function I used the decorated function:

```
def index():
    data = my_cached_function() # no args
```

In another function, I try to invalidate the cache:

```
def new_item():
    cache.invalidate(my_cached_function, 'namespace')
```

Since Beaker cache is configured with `'cache.type': 'memory'`, I've also tried:

```
def new_item():
    cache.invalidate(my_cached_function, 'namespace', type='memory')
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**NOTES**

In a typical scenario, I would call index() most of the time. I need the cache to be cleared whenever new_item() is called, so that the index() call will take into account the new items created by new_item() function.

The application in question is a web application running on top of bottle framework.

Answer (score 2):

You need to invalidate the cache *before* `my_cached_function` is called.  See the [beaker.cache.CacheManager documentation](http://beaker.groovie.org/modules/cache.html#beaker.cache.CacheManager.invalidate) for an example.

Comment: It is called before the my_cached_function in theory. When a user creates a new item the new_item() function is called which is supposed to invalidate the cache. Then, he visits the index page, where the decorated function is called. The index page should be showing the list of items _including_ the new one, but it's not.

Comment: Oh and another note. The cache works even w/o invalidating. I just want to force invalidation.

Comment: Instead of invalidating the cache in `new_item`, try setting a key like `should_invalidate_item_cache` to `True` in the session, and in `index`, invalidate if that value is `True`.  (This is just a guess, not tested.)

Comment: Hm, yeah, that sounds like somehow possible. You see the app is stateless, so I don't have any session mechanism. If I understood your correctly, the invalidation has to occur in the same scope?

Comment: That is my guess, but I didn't actually use Beaker's caching.

Comment: It would explain why it DOESN'T work in my setup anyway. :) I'll try something maybe with a lock file of some sort.